# Combinatorics with points on plane

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

There are 10 non-collinear points(A,B,C,..). How many triangles can we draw, so that they contain AB line? 

My attempt to solve the problem is: 

10C3-2*9C3=48 (10C3 is number of all possible triangles and 9C3 is number of triangles that don't contain A and *2 is because same goes with point B.) The solution is 8 and I understand why (because if we choose only line AB we can choose 8 other different possibilities for the last point).

I don't understand why the attempt I explained above fails (10C3-2*9C3)

Answer (score 2):

I believe your approach fails as you are overcounting triangles.

${9 \choose 3}$ counts the triangles that do not have $A$ as a vertex: you cannot now multiply by two, as you are double-counting those triangles which do not have both $A$  and $B$ as vertices (e.g. FGH is counted twice, as not having $A$ plus as not having $B$ as vertex).

You could instead do as follows: count all the triangles - (triangles that do not contain $A$ nor $B$) - (triangles that contain $A$ but not $B$) - (triangles that contain $B$ but not $A$), in numbers:
$${10 \choose 3} - {8 \choose 3} - 2 {8 \choose 2} = 8$$ as expected.

You might also notice the latter is also equal to
$${10 \choose 3} - 2{8 \choose 3}  = 8$$

Comment: Thank you for the explanation

Comment: @Mirjan Pecenko, glad it could help.